# Delete pictures in background

Tags: release-loki, desktop

The image I put in the background, but I deleted it in the meantime, remained in the settings from the picture. How can I delete it?

l look in file system/usr/share/background but I did not find it there...

http://www.oldschool-samp.com/slike/images/screenaza.png

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be under:

```
/home/username/.local/share/backgrounds
```